# how Implementing a highlight feature for this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, livesearch

this code is being using for live search and i want to highlight each character in the table when i type it in search box so how can i do this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search-box").on("keyup", function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var filter = $('#search-filter').val().toLowerCase();
        if (filter == "listitem") {
            $(".listitem").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        } else {
            $(".td-" + filter).filter(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        }
    });

    $('#search-filter').on("change", function() {
        var value = $("#search-box").val().toLowerCase();
        var filter = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if (filter == "listitem") {
            $(".listitem").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        } else {
            $(".td-" + filter).filter(function() {
                $(this).parent().toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        }
    });

    $(".tbl-btn").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().find('td:not(:first-child)').toggleClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('rotate');
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be better to create a runnable fiddle example by using the `<>` icon on the toolbar. You can pick jquery from the left side of the page, the highest version is 3.3.1, but should be ok for what you have.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I agree with the above comments saying that if you included the html it would make more sense of your code